# Strange behaviour on form.rest()

Tags: angular

The issue is that it seems as if after form.reset() [(ngModel)]="myCodeTable.tableId" disconnects the html from the variable.

I have the following code:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSave(f)" #f="ngForm">

<table class="table-code-table">
    <tr>
        <td class="titleEnglish">
            Table Code
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"
                on-focusout="onLeave()"
                [(ngModel)]="myCodeTable.tableId"  
                id="tableId" 
                class="inputEnglish"
                ngModel
                name="tableId"
                #tableId="ngModel"
                #tableIdEle        
                minlength="1"
                maxlength="3"
                pattern="[0-9]*"
                [attr.disabled]="lockTableCode ? 'disabled' : null"
                required>
```

NOT ALL CODE IS SHOWN

```
    <button (click)="onNew(f)"
        type="button"
        [ngClass]="{rentButton: showAdd, rentButtonDisabled: !showAdd}"
        [attr.disabled]="!showAdd ? 'disabled' : null"
        >New</button>
```

In my component.ts file I have the following code:

```
onNew (myForm: NgForm) {
myForm.reset();
this.myCodeTable.tableId=2;
```

}

Somewhere in my ts file I do "this.myCodeTable.tableId=2;" and I see the "2" in the field on the form.

After having "2" in the field I click the "New" button. This leaves the field empty and I don't see "2" in the field on the form.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Angular.
form.reset() clears all the fields on the form.
For instance

1. myNumber: number = 2;
2. myNumber is bound to the form to field (HTML) name="GoodNumber" [(ngModel)]="myNumber".
3. form.reset() just about does "GoodNumber = null" so the HTML form shows a clear field (empty field).
4. Now change detection runs and since myNumber is still 2 nothing changed and GoodNumber stays empty.
5. I could do myNumber = 2; but still change detection will run see no change in myNumber and do nothing.